# How to filter records with a not null value in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I am trying to select a record with the mimetype field with a non-null value,

```
$file = $DB->get_record('table', array('itemid' => $id_imagen, 'component' => 'user', 'mimetype' => 'is not null'));
```

Is there any way to get this using get_record?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that. As I see in lib/dml/moodle_database.php, in function where_clause, it says if (is_null($value)) { $where[] = "$key IS NULL";, so this would be the right place to put something like if ($value == 'IS NOT NULL') { $where[] = "$key IS NOT NULL";

Answer (score 2):

I answer my own question in case this can help someone

No, it is no possible to use IS NOT NULL or others with get_record function. You can acomplish it using function get_record_sql like this:

```
$file = $DB->get_record_sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemid = " . $id_imagen . " AND component = 'user' AND mimetype IS NOT NULL");
```